# Way to check which certificate haproxy use in runtime?

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I use haproxy, which use ssl certificate in this way:

```
 bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ssl/mycertificate.pem /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ssl/net.pem
```

I change the ssl certificate, and I want to make sure that haproxy uses the new certificate. Is there any way to check it?

Comment: Make a request to the server with a browser and display the cert used, or connect with a tool that displays info about the cert without doing a request like `openssl s_client` (use `-servername` if SNI needed which I believe not for haproxy; use `-showcerts` for full chain) or Java `keytool -printcert -sslserver`. Or if the server is publicly reachable use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to display the cert chain plus lots of other info about the quality of your TLS setup.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks, how can I see the expiration date with openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All together on one line, at the command (shell) prompt:

```
true | 
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com -showcerts |
openssl x509 -text -noout
```

Note that you need to specify the server name twice.

You will see *everything* about the cert, here, including the not-before and not-after validity dates.